# Conditional Scheduled Tasks

Tags: message-queue

I'm currently trying to figure out how to schedule a task in the future efficiently, but only when certain conditions are met. I'm planning a new project so specific technologies haven't been locked in but I'll most likely be using a queue like RabbitMQ.

The system I'll be building will have a bunch of data in separate accounts, and each account can set up different rules and actions to occur when certain conditions are met.

E.g. Do X if field1 = 'abc' and field2 > 200

The immediate rules are of course pretty straight forward, however if it is changed to 'Do X in 3 days if field1 = 'abc' and field2 > 200' then it becomes harder and a ideal solution isn't springing to mind.

When the data is changed and the rule matches I could add a delayed message to the queue so the message is released after 3 days. This would be extremely efficient, no polling, etc... The problem is if during that time the data changes and the rule no longer matches I don't want the action to occur.

Additionally it's possible for the rule to match, then the data is changed so that the rule no longer matches, then the data changed again so it matches again. This should reset the 3 days but it rules out just double checking the rules when the delayed message gets released.

I could store a history of all changes to the data (which I might be doing anyway) but when the delayed message is released it could be expensive trawling through all changes to verify the rule has matched on all occasions.

Its looking like I might need to use a database driven queue, and when data changes re-apply the rules to every message being delayed and delete them if they stop matching.

This kind of thing must come up in a wide range of applications however and I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing delayed messages while the data continues to match rules.

Comment: You might have better luck with this in the software engineering stack exchange as it seems a little woolly and open-ended.

Comment: @pvg when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat perhaps, but I'm not recommending cross-posting.